# How to return value of Sinon fake based on argument of function?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, sinon

I'm trying to avoid use of older Sinon APIs and use Fakes only. Previously, I used to be able to mock the return value of a stub based on an argument like so:

```
sinon.stub().withArgs("arg1").returns("val1")
```

This would return `val1` when `arg1` is passed.

What is the equivalent of achieving this with Sinon fakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"sinon": "^8.1.1"*. There is **no** `sinon.fake.withArgs()` API, instead, we can use `sinon.fake(func)` API.

> Wraps an existing Function to record all interactions, while leaving it up to the `func` to provide the behavior.

> This is useful when complex behavior not covered by the `sinon.fake.*` methods is required or when wrapping an existing function or method.

```js
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('74965194', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub().withArgs('arg1').returns('val1');
    sinon.assert.match(stub('arg1'), 'val1');
  });

  it('should pass too', () => {
    const fake = sinon.fake((arg) => {
      if (arg === 'arg1') return 'val1';
    });
    sinon.assert.match(fake('arg1'), 'val1');
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  74965194
    ✓ should pass
    ✓ should pass too


  2 passing (5ms)
```